# Question on functional maps between sets

Tags: functions, category-theory, set-theory

It I have a set $W$ that has a binary function $f$ defined on it maps 2-tuple combinations of $W$ onto another set $K$, i.e,

$ f: W \times W \rightarrow K$

Here f is non-surjective and non-injective. Let us also introduce another function $g$ that maps $W$ onto another set $V$, i.e,

$ g : W \rightarrow V$

Here let $g$ be both surjective and injective (aka bijective). Lastly introduce another function $y$ that maps 2-tuple combinations of $V$ onto $K$, i.e.

$ y : V \times V \rightarrow K$

With the property

$f(w_{1}, w_{2}) = y(g(w_{1}), g(w_{2}))$

Then what properties must exist on $W$, $K$, $V$, $g$, $f$ and $y$ so that the above statement holds?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as well as any good online tutorials, textbooks, Itunes U Units, etc that can help with this sort of stuff?

Thanks in Advance,
David

Answer (score 1):

If $W,K,V,f$, and $g$ are given, you can simply define $y:V\times V\to K$ to have the desired property by setting

$$y(v_1,v_2)=f\big(g^{-1}(v_1),g^{-1}(v_2)\big)$$

for each $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle\in V\times V$. This makes sense, since $g^{-1}$ is a bijection from $V$ to $W$, and it implies that

$$f(w_1,w_2)=f\big(g^{-1}(g(w_1)),g^{-1}(g(w_2))\big)=y\big(g(w_1),g(w_2)\big)$$

for each $\langle w_1,w_2\rangle\in W\times W$.

Comment: Sorry, I think you meant $g^{-1}$ instead $t^{-1}$.

Comment: @rdias: I did indeed; thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Thanks so much for your response, much clearer now. Do you happen to know any good textbooks on this sort of stuff?
Again thanks for help.

Comment: The extension I have now is if 

$f(w_{1}, w_{2}) \approx y(g(w_{1}) , g(w_{2})) 

Then what are some ideal conditions for this to hold. ... back to the drawing board :-)

Comment: @user3053801: You’re welcome. I really don’t know of anything that concentrates on this sort of thing, I’m afraid.